# How to correctly make a SQL-request with option?

Tags: python, sqlite

Currently `cur.fetchone` returns "None". But if change `ID=?, (number_row,)` for `Id=2` (or other number) all works as planned. Changing "cur.fetchone" to "cur.fetchone" is returning the empty tuple. Where I have I gone wrong?

```
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
con = sqlite3.connect('database_all.db')
power_list = np.array([-70, 200, 300, 400, 480, 520, 600])
temperature = 90
number_row = np.searchsorted(power_list, temperature, side='right')
print(number_row)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT VARIANTS from P_steel_3_2 WHERE ID=?", (number_row,))
pressure_variants = cur.fetchone()
print(pressure_variants)
cur.close()
```

And my table (generated in DB Browser for SQLite)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE "P_steel_3_2" (
    `ID`    INTEGER,
    `TEMPERATURE`   REAL,
    `VARIANTS`  REAL
);
INSERT INTO `P_steel_3_2` (ID,TEMPERATURE,VARIANTS) VALUES (0,'-70_200','0.1, 0.25, 0.4, 0.6 ,1 ,1.6, 2.5 ,4, 6.4, 10, 16');
INSERT INTO `P_steel_3_2` (ID,TEMPERATURE,VARIANTS) VALUES (1,'200-300','0.09, 0.22, 0.36, 0.56, 0.9, 1.4, 2.2, 3.6, 5.6, 9, 14');
INSERT INTO `P_steel_3_2` (ID,TEMPERATURE,VARIANTS) VALUES (2,'300-400','0.08, 0.2, 0.32, 0.5, 0.8, 1.25, 2, 3.2, 5, 8, 12.5');
INSERT INTO `P_steel_3_2` (ID,TEMPERATURE,VARIANTS) VALUES (3,'400-480','0.07, 0.18, 0.28, 0.45, 0.7, 1.1, 1.8, 2.8, 4.5, 7.1, 10.2');
INSERT INTO `P_steel_3_2` (ID,TEMPERATURE,VARIANTS) VALUES (5,'520-600','0.05, 0.11, 0.18, 0.28, 0.45, 0.7, 1.1, 1.8, 2.8, 4.5, 7.1');
INSERT INTO `P_steel_3_2` (ID,TEMPERATURE,VARIANTS) VALUES (6,'600-700','0, 0.06, 0.09, 0.15, 0.22, 0.36, 0.56, 0.9, 1.4, 2.2, 3.6');
INSERT INTO `P_steel_3_2` (ID,TEMPERATURE,VARIANTS) VALUES (4,'480-520','0.06, 0.16, 0.25, 0.4, 0.64, 1, 1.6, 2.5, 4, 6.4, 10');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: What does **Changing "cur.fetchone" to "cur.fetchone"** mean? Did you mean `cur.fetchall`?

Comment: Oops. Of course "cur.fetchall", thank`s.

Answer (score 1):

`np.searchsorted` returns an array of indices, so it's returning `[2]` rather than `2`. You need to extract the element to use it in the query.

```
if number_row.ndim > 0 and number_row.shape[0] > 0:
    id = number_row[0]
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT VARIANTS from P_steel_3_2 WHERE ID=?", (id,))
    pressure_variants = cur.fetchone()
    print(pressure_variants)
    cur.close()
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't know `numpy` uses a different method to get array size. It has `.shape` property that returns a tuple of all the array dimensions.

Comment: When I input you solution i get Typeerror: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len(). For some strange reason type(number_row) is 'numpy.int64'. I added  line "number_row = int(number_row)" and all works good.

Comment: Hmm, I trying use fixed variants and get "IndexError: tuple index out of range" in line "if number_row.shape[0] > 0:"

Comment: I added a check for `number_row.ndim > 0`.

Comment: 'number_row.ndim > 0' is False for any values and 'number_row.shape[0]> 0' stay return "IndexError: tuple index out of range".

Comment: OK, I give up. Someone who actually knows Numpy will have to resolve this. I tried reading blogs and documentation, but I guess I didn't get it.

Comment: I'm just trying to make sure it doesn't go into this block if `np.searchsorted()` doesn't find anything.

Comment: Well, I think I should read more about Numpy. For now, I keep in reserve "number_row = int(number_row)".